# spring cloud eureka server example login challenge

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to check spring cloud's Eureka server but I' mgetting the login dialog.
Does any one knows the default user&password?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're talking about [this application](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/eureka) and you didn't change anything, the login should be "user" and the password should be automatically printed in the console at startup, as this is after all a Spring Boot application ([see reference doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security)).

**Edit:** password is "password" [because it is set in the application properties](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/eureka/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml#L13), see Dave and Spencer's comments.

Comment: If you are using the sample eureka application AND config server, user: uesr, password: password.

Comment: The password is configured for the demo here: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/eureka/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml#L13. the username is "user" (Spencer has fat fingers).

Comment: Grrrr - it was so hard to find the answer to this :(  But thank you very much for those that helped.

Comment: How the heck does a Microservice register itself if the password is only output to the console?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to config:

management.security.enabled=false

this will remove the security.
you can also enable spring security to enable username password