# Eureka client can not register to Eureka server with user/pass

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

Versions:

1. Spring Security: 6.1.4
2. Spring Boot: 3.1.4
3. Spring Clound: 2022.0.4

User needs to login to access Eureka Server's dashboard. So, I configured spring security for Eureka server like below.

Eureka Server:

Config:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${app.eureka.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${app.eureka.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf->csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/eureka/**"))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        UserDetails user = User
                .withUsername(username)
                .password(encoder.encode(password))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

Main app:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DiscoveryServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

server.port=8761
app.eureka.username=eureka
app.eureka.password=password
```

I have one service: product-service

Main app:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ProductServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/product

eureka.client.service-url.defautZone=http://eureka:password@localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
spring.application.name=product-service
server.port=8080
```

My system works fine if I remove auth layer from eureka server and change `eureka.client.service-url.defautZone` back to `http:/localhost:8761/eureka`.

The full error message:

```
2023-10-03T03:05:39.446+07:00 ERROR 36620 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_PRODUCT-SERVICE/host.docker.internal:product-service:8080 - was unable to send heartbeat!

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:837) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1401) ~[eureka-client-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

How can I solve this problem?

I have found some questions on Stack Overflow that have same as my situation. But there are two cases:

1. The solution is not suitable for my version (normally, it's an old version):

   - [How to secure spring cloud eureka service with basic auth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50971891/how-to-secure-spring-cloud-eureka-service-with-basic-auth)
   - https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/security-rest-basic-auth-example/
2. The solution does not resolve my problem properly:

   - [-SpringBoot 3 -Eureka registry server -(username & password registration problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74761559/springboot-3-eureka-registry-server-username-password-registration-problem)
   - [spring cloud eureka server example login challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267443/spring-cloud-eureka-server-example-login-challenge?rq=3)
   - [Not able to register a service as Eureka Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605508/not-able-to-register-a-service-as-eureka-client?rq=3)
   - [Unable to register client to eureka server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44108609/unable-to-register-client-to-eureka-server?rq=3)
   - [Unable to register services to the discovery server (EUREKA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53702627/unable-to-register-services-to-the-discovery-server-eureka?rq=3)
   - [Spring Eureka asks for username password authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60503707/spring-eureka-asks-for-username-password-authentication?rq=3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by changing my **application.yaml** file. Before it was like this:

```
eureka:
   client:
     service-url:
       default-zone: http://eureka:password@localhost:8761/eureka
```

And I changed it to:

```
eureka:
   client:
     serviceUrl:
       defaultZone: http://eureka:password@localhost:8761/eureka
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, this is amazing, it's work for me

Comment: You are welcome. Glad you fixed it!  :)

Comment: can I ask one more question about Micrometer?